# how to get image from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a given table structure

```
     |   ID    |             IMAGE                | 
     |   01    |           123.jpg                |    
     |   02    |  http://localhost/test/logo.jpg  |    
     |   03    |  http://localhost/test/pic.jpg   |    
     |   04    |           image.png              |
```

i am getting images as shown below

```
$qry="SELECT IMAGE FROM `table`";
$res=mysql_query($qry);
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res)){
    if($row[0])
    {
       $pic="http://localhost/test/".$row[0];
    }
    else
    {
        $pic="";
    }
    echo $pic;
}
```

but it not working correctly for 02,03 images

Comment: What is the value outputted of $pic?

Comment: for 01)http://localhost/test/123.jpg    for02)http://localhost/test/http://localhost/test/logo.jpg out is like above

Comment: How about checking whether `$row[0]` already starts with "http://" or "https://" and only prepending the full URL when it doesn't?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar:for 1 & 4  there is no path

Comment: @Suresh: I know. Look at my answer.

Comment: Really, you're asking for help with such trivial matter? First record gives you a filename, other two give you a URL, which you glue to another URL. And you wonder what's wrong? Is this worth posting on SO? Even if you're a beginner, stuff like these are things you **should** work out on your own, otherwise what are you even doing in programming niche?

Answer (score 2):

The following only prepends the full URL when the given value doesn't yet start with "http://" or "https://":

```
if($row[0])
{
    if (stripos($pic, "http://") === false && stripos($pic, "https://") === false)
        $pic="http://localhost/test/".$row[0];
    else
        $pic=$row[0];
}
else
{
    $pic="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a standard way you're storing images in your table.  If those are the only formats, you'll need add some sort of check before putting your image string together.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res)){
if($row[0])
   {
   if
   $pic = (strpos($row[0], "//") === false) ? "http://localhost/test/".$row[0]: $row[0];
   }
   else
   {
   $pic="";
   }
echo $pic;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you change your code from

```
 $pic="http://localhost/test/".$row[0];
```

to

```
 $pic="http://localhost/test/".$row[1];
```

because your image column is $row[1]

Comment: The query is just grabbing the `image` column

Comment: No it isn't. Only one column is being queried. That makes it `$row[0]`

Comment: my bad ... i did not look at query correctly

Answer (score -1):

Well, obviously you get this URL for images 02 and 03:

```
http://localhost/test/http://localhost/test/logo.jpg
http://localhost/test/http://localhost/test/pic.jpg
```

which obviously are bad formed. 
Maybe you want to add this to your code...

```
if($row[0])
   {
   if (strpos($row[0],'/')) {
     $pic=$row[0];
   } else {
   $pic="http://localhost/test/".$row[0];
   }
} else ...
```

Comment: Checking for "/" is not enough, as `$row[0]` may contain something like `pathcomponent/file.jpg`, which would have to have the protocol-part prepended.